# Core Data: NSManagedObject property changes briefly when saving nested MOCs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

### The Setup

My app uses nested Core Data Managed Object Contexts. The **parent** context is on the main thread. When I need to do work, I create a **child** context on a background GCD serial queue.

In this child context, I create a new entity: `LPProject` which has a BOOL property: `valid`.

I set this property to `YES` when I create the object. When I'm done, I save the child MOC to push these changes back to the parent context.

---

### The Problem

On the main thread, I have an `NSTreeController` that powers an `NSOutlineView`. This TreeController is bound to my main MOC and fetches its content from there.

The trouble is that as soon as I save the **child** MOC, the TreeController re-fetches its content (as it should) BUT the value of the new `LPProject` entity's `valid` property is `NO` when it should be `YES`.

I've added a bunch of logging statements and here's what I'm seeing. (Note: error-handling has been removed to simplify. As has obtaining permanent IDs for the newly inserted managedObjects before saving the child context):

```
// Here, we are in a background GCD queue, working on the CHILD context.

NSLog(@"About to save child context. Project Valid?: %i, [newProject.valid boolValue]);  // Result: Project IS valid.

[childContext save:NULL];

//
// RIGHT HERE is where the NSTreeController re-fetches and updates its content. See note below
//    

NSLog(@"Saved child context. Project Valid?: %i", [newProject.valid boolValue]);  // Result: Project IS valid. 

NSManagedObjectID *projectID = [newProject.objectID retain];

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{
    // self.managedObjectContext is the main-thread, parent context.
    LPProject *affectedProject = (LPProject *)[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:projectID];
    NSLog(@"Back on main thread, project valid?: %i", [affectedProject.valid boolValue]);  // Result: project IS valid.
```

#### WTF?

The `LPProject` entity's `valid` property is `YES` at all points that I log it. However, when the TreeController refetches its content (which happens at the point indicated above), it shows the newly added project with `NO` for `valid`, even though that same project will show `YES` at the next NSLog statement after the child context saves.

This happens **randomly**, roughly 50% of the time. I'm at a bit of a loss to explain it or fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably show the code for the mocDidSave notification handler that the mainQueue MOC uses.  You're also not programatically doing the `fetch` or `reloadData`, right?  Those can be asynchronous in unexpected ways.

Comment: There is no -didSave notification used for the main queue's MOC. That's the whole point of nested MOCs---the notification pattern was the old way to do threading before Apple added support for child contexts. And nope; I'm not manually fetching or calling reloadData.

Comment: I *think* what's happening is that because I'm using bindings, when I call "-save" on the child MOC, the parent MOC is sending out an NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange notification, which the treeController is handling. THAT triggers a call to -reloadItem:reloadChildren: in the NSOutlineView. And THAT is when the "valid" property is NO, even though it's YES everywhere else AND it's YES when I subsequently call -reloadData on the outlineView to force a reload.

Comment: So... why would the "valid" property be NO when the MOC issues that notification? That notification is what's triggering the reload of the outlineView. I would expect Core Data to only issue it AFTER it has fully integrated the changes from the child context to the parent context.

Comment: And an aside: the outlineView draws its contents differently if the project entity for a given row is not valid. So the initial reload (triggered by the MOC notification) draws the row as if the project is not valid and then calling -reloadData on the outlineView a split second later obviously redraws the row as valid.

Comment: Bryan you're right.  The notification is the old pattern.  But so is not using `performBlockAndWait` in place of `dispatch_async`...  the "new" pattern has those `performBlock` wrappers around the GCD functions that are a necessity to get code to work right with a mix of `PrivateQueue` and `MainQueue` concurrency.  A missing `performBlock` might be the issue.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code -- which is always necessary with core data since it has so many interrelated parts -- it's hard to tell.  However, I have a few questions...  when you say background GCD queue, what do you mean?  When you save from the child, do you also save on the parent?  What are the details of your fetch request - does it go to the store, or fetch from its cache?  With nested contexts, you can get refresh from the cache, depending on how its done.  So, what you describe may or may not be strange, depending on your code... but all of that is missing...